# Changing scale on y-axis of highcharts to display time

Tags: jquery, mysql, highcharts

I'm having trouble with Highcharts displaying time on the y-axis. I've tried a couple of things without success. My time duration (charting length of a baby's nap) is being passed in seconds, but I'd like to chart it in h:m:s.
Javascript:

```
$('#napContainer').highcharts({
        title: {
            text: 'Nap Chart'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                day: '%e. %b'
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            floor: 0,
            type: 'datetime', //y-axis will be in milliseconds
            dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                second: '%H:%M:%S',
            },
            pointInterval: 3600 * 1000
        },
        series: [{
            data: {{ json_encode($napData, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK) }}
        }]

    });
```

From my event controller, gathering info from MySQL:

```
 $napData = array();

    $naps = $baby->naps()->orderBy('start', 'ASC')->get();
    foreach ($naps as $nap)
    {
        $napData[] = [
            $nap->start->timestamp * 1000,
            $nap->end->diffInSeconds($nap->start)
        ];
    }
```

Comment: To clarify, my y-axis is displaying in milliseconds, starting with Jan 1. I want it to measure time durations, not dates and moments in time.

Comment: Could you paste you json?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// tickInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000, // one day
labels: {
format: '{value:%a %d %b}',
align: 'right',
rotation: -30
},
```

Comment: Doesn't change my output.